# Scheme: Why am I getting this error: assertion-violation: argument of wrong type [car (car #{Unspecific})

Tags: error-handling, functional-programming, scheme

I believe I have found it to be this function in my program but seems to fail before it even gets to the first line of `find_best_candidates` function:

```
(define (count-the-score candList voterList)
    (display "Spot 3")
    (cond
        ((null? voterList) 0)
        
        (else
            (cond 
                ((or (= (car candList) 0) (= (car voterList) 0)) (+ 0 (count-the-score (cdr candList)(cdr voterList))))
                ((equal? (car candList) (car voterList)) (+ 1 (count-the-score (cdr candList)(cdr voterList))))
                (else (- (count-the-score (cdr candList) (cdr voterList)) 1))
            )
        )
    )
)

(define (find-max myList)
    (define sortedList 0)
    (display "Spot 4")
    (cond 
        ((null? myList) myList)
        ((null? (cdr myList)) myList)
        
        (else
            (set! sortedList (find-max (cdr myList)))
            
            (cond   
                ((null? sortedList) (cdr myList))
                ((null? (car sortedList)) (car myList))
                ((null? (car myList)) sortedList)
                ((= (car (cdr (car myList))) (car (cdr (car sortedList))))
                 (append sortedList (list (car myList)))
                 )
                 ((> (car (cdr (car myList))) (car (cdr (car sortedList))))
                  (list (car myList))
                )
                
                (else 
                    sortedList
                )
            )
            (display "Spot 5")
        )
    )
)

(define (find_best_candidates Voter Candidates)
    (display "Spot 2")
    (define best 0)
    (define score 0)
    (define voterScore 0)
    (define tempScore 0)
    (define max_till 0) 
    
    (cond 
        ((null? Candidates) '())
        
        (else
            (set! best (find_best_candidates Voter (cdr Candidates)))
            
            (set! score (count-the-score Voter (cdr (car Candidates))))
            
            (set! voterScore (list (car (car Candidates)) score))
            
            (set! tempScore (append best (list voterScore)))
            
            (set! max_till (find-max best))
            
        )
    )
    (display "Spot 6")
)


(define (fetch-names myList)
    (display "Spot 7")
    (define prev_ans 0)
    (define ll 0)
        (cond 
            ((null? (cdr myList)) (list(car (car myList))))
            
            (else 
                
                (set! prev_ans (fetch-names (cdr) myList))
                
                (set! ll (append (list (car (car myList))) prev_ans))
                ll
            )   
        )
        (display "Spot 8")
        
)


;Main function;
(define (best_candidates Voter Candidates)
    (display "Spot 1")
    (fetch-names (find_best_candidates Voter Candidates))
    (display "Spot END")
)
```

The data the is being imported is as follows:

```
(define (test1)
(best_candidates 
    '(           0   0   0   1   1   1  -1  -1  -1   1)
    '((Adams     1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1)
      (Grant    -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1)
      (Polk      1  -1   1  -1   1  -1   1  -1   1  -1)
      (Jackson   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0)
      (Taft      0  -1   0  -1   0  -1   0  -1   0  -1)
      (Ford      1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0)
      (Madison   0   0   0   1  -1   0   0  -1   1   1)))
)
; should return (adams ford madison)
```

The error I end up receiving is:

```
assertion-violation: argument of wrong type [car]
                     (car #{Unspecific})
```

Comment: The combination of `define` and `set!` makes it look like you're trying to program in some other language but with Scheme syntax. Scheme programs very rarely use `set!`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my issue. In `fetch-names` function, I had `(set! prev_ans (fetch-names (cdr) myList))` which should have been written as `(set! prev_ans (fetch-names (cdr myList)))`. I misplaced a parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

The result of the last expression in a function body is the result returned to the callee. Eg.

```
(define (best_candidates Voter Candidates)
  (display "Spot 1")
  (fetch-names (find_best_candidates Voter Candidates))
  (display "Spot END"))
```

Will return the implementation defined "undefined value" as required by specification of `display`. In Racket it looks like `#<void>` and it is the same object from all of the procedures that are supposed to return an undefined value. Note that it is only undefined in the standard while in an implementation it is very defined so in Racket you can capture it in a variable. `set!` also returns an undefined value.

Some of your code expects a list, but gets `#{Unspecific}` which is probably your implementations version of the undefined value. Since it's not a pair `car` will signal an error.

If you payed for your Scheme course and learned to use `display` and `set!` your should ask for your money back. It's as if you already know a C language and try to assimilate Scheme. While you can learn Python that way since it is a C dialect, Scheme is not a C dialect so assimilation mostly works between lisp dialects and not across different language families.